# Navigation Guards beforeEach infinite loop

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Trying to use navigation guard, but `next('/auth/login')` gives infinite loop:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  auth.validate().then((valid) => {
    if (!valid) {
      next('/auth/login')
    } else {
      next()
    }
  })
})
```

router is define:

```
const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      name: 'login',
      path: '/auth/login',
      component: login
    }
})
```

Comment: I posted a solution for vue-router v4.x here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68009594/1219079

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me like when your auth is not valid your router is sending you to `/auth/login` and on that page you get sent again. I handle this differently in my app, but with your code you can add a way to check where the page is comming from, using the `from` object in your route.

You need something to check if current route is `/auth/login` then ignore don't redirect.

example:

```
 if (!valid && from.path !== '/auth/login') {}
```

This will not redirect back to /auth/login because you are coming from that page.

Comment: You me an idea, but I guess it shoud be to.path !== '/auth/login'?

Comment: Yes, that might also be better

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into a similar issue the last time. In my case, I have pages that are public and others that need authorization. I added an `isPublic: boolean` property to the meta object.
In your case, it would have been

```
(!valid && isPublic === false) ? next({ path: '/auth/login' }) : next();
```

I hope this helps. I am open to corrections too. Thanks