# NavigationDuplicated Navigating to current location ("/search") is not allowed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When I want to do a search multiple times it shows me the `NavigationDuplicated` error. My search is in the navbar and the way I have configured the search is to take the value using a model and then pass the value as a parameter to the ContentSearched component, and then receive the value of the search in that component.

I know the right way is to use an emitter, but I still don't know how to learn to use it. To access the emit is `context.emit('', someValue)`

```sh
NavigationDuplicated {_name: "NavigationDuplicated", name: "NavigationDuplicated", message: "Navigating to current location ("/search") is not allowed", stack: "Error↵    at new NavigationDuplicated (webpack-int…node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:1853:26)"}
```

**NavBar.vue**

```
<template>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-nav" v-bind:class="{'navbarOpen': show }">
    <div class="container">
      <router-link to="/" class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="../assets/logo.png" alt="Horizon Anime" id="logo">
      </router-link>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" v-on:click.prevent="toggleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" v-bind:class="{'show': show }">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link class="nav-link" to="/" ><i class="fas fa-compass"></i> Series</router-link>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link class="nav-link" :to="{name: 'EpisodesSection'}" ><i class="fas fa-compact-disc"></i> Episodios</router-link>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link class="nav-link" :to="{name: 'MovieSection'}" ><i class="fas fa-film"></i> Peliculas</router-link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="search-bar">
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" v-model="query" type="search" placeholder="Buscar películas, series ..." aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-main my-2 my-sm-0" @click.prevent="goto()" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
  import {value} from 'vue-function-api';
  import {useRouter} from '@u3u/vue-hooks';

  export default {
    name: "NavBar",
    setup(context){
      const {router} = useRouter();
      const query = value("");

      let show = value(true);
      const toggleNavbar = () => show.value = !show.value;      
      
      const goto = () =>{
        let to = {name: 'ContentSearched' , params:{query: query}}
        router.push(to);
      };
        
      return{
        show,
        toggleNavbar,
        goto,
        query
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**ContentSearched.vue**

```js
<template>
   <div class="container">
     <BoxLink/>
    <main class="Main">
      <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
        Resultados para "{{query}}"
      </div>
      <div v-if="isLoading">
        <!-- <img class="loading" src="../assets/loading.gif" alt="loading"> -->
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        <ul class="ListEpisodios AX Rows A06 C04 D02">
          <li v-for="(content, index) in contentSearched" :key="index">
            <div v-if="content.type === 'serie'">
              <Series :series="content"/>
            </div>
            <div v-if="content.type === 'pelicula'">
              <Movies :movies="content"/>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  import {onCreated} from "vue-function-api"
  import {useState , useRouter , useStore} from '@u3u/vue-hooks';
  import BoxLink from "../components/BoxLink";
  import Movies from "../components/Movies";
  import Series from "../components/Series";

  export default{
    name: 'ContentSearched',
    components:{
      BoxLink,
      Movies,
      Series
    },
    setup(context){
      const store = useStore();
      const {route} = useRouter();

      const state = {
        ...useState(['contentSearched' , 'isLoading'])
      };

      const query = route.value.params.query;

      onCreated(() =>{
        store.value.dispatch('GET_CONTENT_SEARCH' , query.value);
      });
      return{
        ...state,
        query,
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 148, accepted):

This happened to me when I had a `router-link` pointing to the same route. e.g. `/products/1`.

> The user is able to click on the products, **but if a product was already clicked (and the component view was already loaded)** and the user attempts to click it again, the error/warning shows in the console.

You can learn more [on the github issue.](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2872).

Posva, one of the main contributors of vue-router suggests:

> router.push('your-path').catch(err => {})

However, if you don't want to have a `catch` block which does nothing, in order to solve the issue you can compare the router navigation with the current route **and only navigate if they differ:**

```
const path = `/products/${id}`
if (this.$route.path !== path) this.$router.push(path)
```

Note: `$route` is an object provided by vue-router to every component. See [The Route Object](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#the-route-object) for more info.

Comment: Note that this solution will also prevent you from going from `/showPhoto?photo_id=1` to `/showPhoto?photo_id=2`.  So it might be easier to just try/catch it -- see for more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/65326844

Answer (score 53):

I think the best solution to this problem can be implemented at the root level if we are not going to further use `Router.push` as asynchronous call.

```
import Router from 'vue-router';

const originalPush = Router.prototype.push;
Router.prototype.push = function push(location) {
  return originalPush.call(this, location).catch(err => err)
};

Vue.use(Router);
```

Comment: Halleluja!
Though I had this error even when using router-link! On Github posva claims this workaround would be necessary only when using router.push() but not for router-link. Any Idea why I still get this error when using router-link (and get rid off when using your code)?

Comment: @TechNomad you can use `$router.beforeEach'` hook and in that use `next(false)` to terminate the navigation

Comment: @TechNomad, the NavigationDuplicated is generated prior to the `$router.beforeEach` is called.

Answer (score 42):

If you are not feeling comfortable catching all kind of errors, I think this implementation is more considerate:

```
this.$router.push("path").catch(error => {
  if (error.name != "NavigationDuplicated") {
    throw error;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 26):

## As of 2021, global configuration :

I only wanted to silence `NavigationDuplicated` error, an empty catch can be dangerous. So I did this :

```js
const router = new VueRouter({/* ... */})

const originalPush = router.push
router.push = function push(location, onResolve, onReject)
{
    if (onResolve || onReject) {
        return originalPush.call(this, location, onResolve, onReject)
    }
 
    return originalPush.call(this, location).catch((err) => {
        if (VueRouter.isNavigationFailure(err)) {
            return err
        }
   
        return Promise.reject(err)
    })
}
```

Insert this once when you initialize vue-router.
**Thanks to *@Oleg Abrazhaev* for the update.**

Comment: there is a better solution here https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2881#issuecomment-520554378

Comment: you can also specify the navigation failure type to ignore with `if (VueRouter.isNavigationFailure(err, NavigationFailureType.duplicated)) {...}` [navigation failure type reference](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-failures.html#detecting-navigation-failures)

Answer (score 20):

I encountered the same problem while searching. My solution is to add `timestamp` to the `this.$route.query` parameters of the search page.

```
this.$router.push({
    path: "/search",
    query: {
      q: this.searchQuery,
      t: new Date().getTime(),
    }
  });
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, this is great answer. Other answers silence the `NavigationDuplicated` error, but this allows to actually navigate to the same route. That allows to navigate to the same route but with different params. In my case I needed that for unit testing.

Comment: Greate answer, direct and simple

Comment: I would say this solution is extremely smart.

Comment: Great and smart solution! This actually allows navigating to the same route again, which I wanted in my case.

Answer (score 18):

if you are using router.push in your code and you don't care about the navigation failing, you should catch it by using catch:

```
router.push('/location').catch(err => {})
```

Answer (score 16):

in manual:

```
router.push(location, onComplete?, onAbort?)
```

You can use more simply

```
router.push("/", () => {});
```

Comment: This one should be the preferred, cleaner way

Answer (score 4):

You mixed multiple concepts here from `router-link`s to programmatic navigation, to query params to a state store. That makes it a bit difficult to help you and tell you what the "correct" solution here is.

Nonetheless, I think the best approach for you would be to:
1) define your route as

```
{
  path: "/search/:searchString",
  component: MySearchComponent,
  props: true
}
```

2) use a responsive `<router-link>` instead of your `router.push`

```
<input type="text" v-model="searchString">
<router-link :to="'/search/'+searchString" tag="button">search</router-link>
```

3) access the `searchString` in your search component via `props: ['searchString']` and `this.searchString`

```
props: ['searchString'],
...
computed: {
  msg() {
    return `Searching for, ${this.searchString}!`;
  }
}
```

Full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-routing-example-9zc6g
Note, I just forked the first codesandbox with a `router` I could find, adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

For TypeScript it worked like this

```
const superPush = VueRouter.prototype.push

VueRouter.prototype.push = async function push(loc:RawLocation):Promise<Route> {
  try {
    return await superPush.bind(this)(loc)
  } catch (e) {
    if (e?.name === 'NavigationDuplicated') {
      console.warn(e)
      return e
    } else {
      throw e
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The question is not about TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very late to the party, but I thought I'd add my solution to this issue as it isn't listed: I simply placed an intermediate searching page as a pass-through to the search results view. I am now using this page for doing some preprocessing of the search terms.

The page template simply is:

```
<template>
  <div>searching ...</div>
</template>
```

The NavigationDuplicated error is now gone and as an added benefit because I perform the fetch in this intermediate page, the responsibility for error-handling is isolated from both the search bar and the results view.

Answer (score 1):

I post here the solution I found, because I was not able to find it well documented somewhere, and I went through it by trial and error.
It could be useful to someone, or someone may fix my misunderstood interpretation of vue-router guards.

It make use of vue-router V4.x and a global `beforeEach` guard.

The use cases are:

1. user asks for `https://app.com/` without being already authorized;
2. user asks for `https://app.com/` being already authorized;
3. user asks for any available routing, which requires auth or not.

**Routes:**

```js
const routes = [
  /**
   * Routes not requiring auth
   */
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/NotAuthorizedLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        name: 'LOGIN',
        component: () => import('pages/Login.vue') 
      },
      {
        path: 'emailsignup',
        component: () => import('pages/EmailSignup.vue') 
      },
      {
        path: 'forgottenpassword',
        component: () => import('pages/ForgottenPassword.vue') 
      }
    ]
  },

  /**
   * Routes requiring auth
   */
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/AuthorizedLayout.vue'),
    meta: { requiresAuth: true },
    children: [
      { 
        path: 'authors',
        name: 'AUTHORS',
        component: () => import('pages/Authors.vue') 
      },
      { path: 'profile', component: () => import('pages/userProfile/index.vue') }
    ]
  }
];
```

**beforeEach global guard:**

```js
  const redirectToLogin = route => {
    const LOGIN = 'LOGIN';
    if (route.name != LOGIN) {
      return { name: LOGIN, replace: true, query: { redirectFrom: route.fullPath } };
    }
  };

  const redirectToHome = route => {
    const DEFAULT = 'AUTHORS';
    return { name: DEFAULT, replace: true };
  };

  Router.beforeEach((to, from) => {
    const userIsAuthenticated = store.getters['authentication/userIsAuthenticated'];
    const requiresAuth = to.matched.some((route) => route.meta && route.meta.requiresAuth);

    if (!userIsAuthenticated && to.fullPath === '/') {
      return redirectToLogin(to);
    }

    if (!userIsAuthenticated && requiresAuth) {
      return redirectToLogin(to);
    }

    if (to.fullPath === '/') {
      return redirectToHome(to);
    }

    return true;
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather old.

Your error is the "@click.prevent". This statement does not work, because your button is a submit button (so your event is called twice).

Use "@submit.prevent" should work (or change the type of your button).

Comment: Instead of changing the template, you can use "prevent default" in your "goto()" method.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would be:

```
import { isNavigationFailure, NavigationFailureType } from 'vue-router/src/util/errors';    
this.$router.push(...).catch((error) => {
      if (!isNavigationFailure(error, NavigationFailureType.duplicated))
        throw error
    );
  }
```

See the [Vue Router docs](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-failures.html#navigationfailuretype)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a mix of extending `prototype` with check `Navigation Duplicated Error`. Other errors and warning should be visible. After a week on production - no `NavigationDuplicated` and everything is working.

```
import { equals } from 'ramda'

export function register(Vue) {
  const routerPush = Router.prototype.push
  const routerReplace = Router.prototype.push

  const isNavigationDuplicated = (currentRoute, nextRoute) => {
    const { name: nextName, params: nextParams = {}, query: nextQuery = {} } = nextRoute
    const { name, params, query } = currentRoute

    return equals(nextQuery, query) && equals(nextParams, params) && equals(nextName, name)
  }

  Router.prototype.push = function push(location) {
    if (!isNavigationDuplicated(this.currentRoute, location)) {
      return routerPush.call(this, location)
    }
  }

  Router.prototype.replace = function replace(location) {
    if (!isNavigationDuplicated(this.currentRoute, location)) {
      return routerReplace.call(this, location)
    }
  }

  Vue.use(Router)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that error comes up when I tried to replace url query parameter with same value.

I have select filters and url query string params are in sync with their values. It works well as long as you change to a new value. If value remains the same (for example coming back from history) and thus replacing query string parameter with same value, error pops out.

Solution was to check if value is changed, and then replace query param in router:

```
let newValue = 'foo'; // new query value for parameter
let qcopy = { ...this.$route.query }; // clone current query
// prevent NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location
if (qcopy['your_param'] != newValue){
  qcopy['your_param'] = newValue;
  this.$router.replace({query: qcopy});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Stop the click propagation from hitting the router action**

I have a high-level answer here that may be useful to others. It may not directly answer the OP, but this thinking applies.

My take on this is to NOT fiddle around with global configuration or attempt to catch router logic. It doesn't make sense to pollute your app with exceptions all over the place.

In the case of a results view with filters. If the filters happen to be presented as router links (for various reasons), but we don't want actual router logic to occur when they're clicked.

So, capture the click before it gets to the router action!

Then you get the best of both worlds:

**Search filters (as a link) that...**

1. Do logic within a view
2. Still provide the benefit of being presented as a link
   (benefits to bot scans, user convenience and accessibility, etc)

### **Technique:**

Use `@click.prevent` on a child *inside* the `router-link`, to capture and stop the click from hitting the router.

### **Example:**

**Before:**
Router logic occurs, even though we're in the route already

```
<router-link class="nav-link" :to="{name: 'MovieSection'}" >
    <i class="fas fa-film"></i>Peliculas
</router-link>
```

**After:**
Router logic inhibited, we run other logic (applyFilter)

```
<router-link class="nav-link" :to="{name: 'MovieSection'}" >
    <div @click.prevent="myFunc(something)">
        <i class="fas fa-film"></i>Peliculas
    </div>
</router-link>
```

With this approach you may avoid messy high-level exceptions in your app.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in the router/index.js init. You can catch can handle the exception types or message you want in the call() method to ignore certain conditions or throw certain ones.

See

> //HANDLE ROUTE ERRORS HERE

comment

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

import routes from "./routes";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

/*
 * If not building with SSR mode, you can
 * directly export the Router instantiation;
 *
 * The function below can be async too; either use
 * async/await or return a Promise which resolves
 * with the Router instance.
 */

export default function(/* { store, ssrContext } */) {
  const router = new VueRouter({
    scrollBehavior: () => ({ x: 0, y: 0 }),
    routes,

    // Leave these as they are and change in quasar.conf.js instead!
    // quasar.conf.js -> build -> vueRouterMode
    // quasar.conf.js -> build -> publicPath
    mode: "history"
  });

  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {
      var token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
      if (token != null) {
        var decodedtoken = JSON.parse(atob(token.split(".")[1]));
        var role =
          decodedtoken[
            "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"
          ];
        if (role != "Admin") {
          next("/accessdenied");
        } else {
          next();
        }
      } else {
        next("/login");
      }
    } else {
      next();
    }

    if (to.meta.requiresLogin) {
      var token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
      if (token != null) {
        next();
      } else {
        next("/login");
      }
    }
  });


 //HANDLE ROUTE ERRORS HERE
  const originalPush = router.push;
  router.push = function push(location) {
    return originalPush.call(this, location).catch(err => {
      console.warn("router>index.js>push()", err);
    });
  };

  return router;
}
```

Based on @Abhishek Shastri's answer

Answer (score -2):

Here's is a simple and efficient solution:

```
if(from.fullPath === to.fullPath){
    return
}
```

Comment: @hero592 Please read through the [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct)  and refrain from making such comments. We all are here to help others and not indulge in such unacceptable practices.