# How to use router-link "to" prop on vuetify components?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an avatar image, upon click I'd like to route to one of my paths. I understand I can do it with router-view, but also that vuetify inherits its properties.

What is missing?:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar>
      <v-toolbar-items>
      <v-avatar to="'/profile'">
        <v-img src="http://www.dumpaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/00-156-750x280.jpg"></v-img>
      </v-avatar>
      </v-toolbar-items>
    </v-app-bar>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

full example:

https://codepen.io/toit123/pen/GRRmpqq

Comment: I didn't get your question. What exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: My example shows a failed use of the ":to" property, as in
<router-link to="/profile"></router-link>

Must there be a way to use "to" within the "v-avatar" component, right?

Comment: duplicated with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57837758/navigationduplicated-navigating-to-current-location-search-is-not-allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-avatar` isn't a link abd doesn't support `to` so you have to wrap your image with a router link like:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar>
      <v-toolbar-items>
        <router-link to="/profile">
          <v-avatar>
            <v-img src="http://www.dumpaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/00-156-750x280.jpg"></v-img>
          </v-avatar>
        </router-link>
      </v-toolbar-items>
    </v-app-bar>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

---

Or you add a custom click event on the v-avatar and do the routing in a method like

```
<v-avatar @click="forward">
```

JS

```
methods: {
  forward() {
     this.$router.push("/profile")
  }
}
```

Comment: When you put a colon before the property name (`:to` in your case), the value (`/profile` in your case) will be interpreted as JavaScript code, therefore your example will fail. Please edit the answer and remove the colon. Thanks.