# How to use Vue Js router in firestore docChanges function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, es6-promise, vue-router

I am developing an online game for 2 players using Vue js and Firestore.

**The game starts as follows:**
The active user will choose a random person from online users and play games with him.

**When the new game button is clicked;**

1. A random player will be selected from online users.
2. A new game room will be created: game number and player information will be saved in the firestore database.
3. For the random user selected, game number and opponent information will be matched.
4. Both users will be directed to the Game page.

**My codes**

```js
import db from "@/firebase/init";
export default {
    name: "Home",
    data() {
        return {
            activeUsers: [],
            currentUser: null,
            opponent: null,
            gameNo: null
        };
    },
    created() {
        this.currentUser = this.$session.get("user");
        this.createOnlineUser();
        this.getOnlineUsers();
    },
    methods: {
        createOnlineUser() {
            let ref = db.collection("game_users").doc(this.currentUser.email);
            ref.get().then(doc => {
                if (!doc.exists) {
                    ref.set({
                        user_id: this.currentUser.id,
                        username: this.currentUser.username,
                        is_play: false
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        getOnlineUsers() {
            db.collection("game_users")
                .where("is_play", "==", false)
                .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
                        let doc = change.doc;

                        var user = {
                            user_id: doc.data().user_id,
                            username: doc.data().username,
                            email: doc.id
                        };

                        if (change.type === "added") {
                            if (doc.data().user_id != this.currentUser.id) {
                                let userIndex = this.activeUsers.findIndex(
                                    element => element.user_id == user.user_id
                                );
                                if (userIndex === -1) {
                                    this.activeUsers.push(user);
                                }
                            }
                        } else if (change.type === "removed") {
                            this.activeUsers = this.activeUsers.filter(element => {
                                return element.user_id != user.user_id;
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
        },
        newGame() {
            this.opponent = this.randomUser();
            this.createGameRoom();
        },
        createGameRoom() {
            this.gameNo = Date.now();
            db.collection("game_rooms")
                .add({
                    gameNo: this.gameNo,
                    players: [this.currentUser.email, this.opponent.email],
                })
                .then(() => {
                    this.addGameNoSession();
                })
                .then(() => {
                    this.createGameAndOpponent();
                });
        },
        createGameAndOpponent() {
            db.collection("game_rooms").onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
                    if (change.type == "added") {
                        let doc = change.doc;
                        let players = doc.data().players;
                        let currentUserIndex = players.indexOf(this.currentUser.email);
                        if (currentUserIndex != -1) {
                            if (!this.$session.exists("gameNo")) {
                                this.gameNo = doc.data().gameNo;
                                this.addGameNoSession();
                            }
                        }
                        this.addOpponentSession(currentUserIndex, players);
                        this.$router.push({ name: "Game" });
                    }
                });
            });
        },
        addGameNoSession() {
            this.$session.set("gameNo", this.gameNo);
        },
        randomUser() {
            var item = this.activeUsers[
                Math.floor(Math.random() * this.activeUsers.length)
            ];
            return item;
        },
        addOpponentSession(currentUserIndex, players) {
            let opponent = null,
                opponentIndex = null;
            if (currentUserIndex == 0) {
                opponentIndex = 1;
            } else {
                opponentIndex = 0;
            }
            opponent = this.activeUsers.find(
                user => user.email === players[opponentIndex]
            );
            this.$session.set("opponent", opponent);
        },
    }
};
```

```html
<template>
  <div id="home">
    <Navbar />
    <div class="home container">
      <div class="card">
        <a  @click="newGame"> New Game
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Vue Router - index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import Game from '../views/Game.vue'
import Login from '../views/auth/Login.vue'
import Signup from '../views/auth/Signup.vue'
Vue.use(VueRouter)



const routes = [{
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home,
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
        }
    }, {
        path: '/game',
        name: 'Game',
        component: Game,
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'Login',
        component: Login
    },
    {
        path: '/signup',
        name: 'Signup',
        component: Signup
    }

]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
})


router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(rec => rec.meta.requiresAuth)) {

        if (Vue.prototype.$session.exists('user')) {
            next()
        } else {
            next({ name: 'Login' })
        }
    } else {
        if (Vue.prototype.$session.exists('user')) {

            if (to.name == "Login" || to.name == "Signup") {
                next({ name: 'Home' })
            }
        }
        next()
    }
})

export default router
```

**I'm checking inside the createGameAndOpponent function:**

If there is a change in "game_rooms" or a new game has been created, find the opponent from online users and redirect both users to the game page.
But there is an error during the redirection here.
The page is not redirected and gives the following error.

**But I get the error below**

> > "Uncaught (in promise)"

**Error Detail:**

> > vue-router.esm.js:2086 Uncaught (in promise) NavigationDuplicated {_name: "NavigationDuplicated", name: "NavigationDuplicated", message: "Navigating to current location ("/game") is not allowed", stack: "Error↵    at new NavigationDuplicated (webpack-int…c/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:175:31)"}_name: "NavigationDuplicated"name: "NavigationDuplicated"message: "Navigating to current location ("/game") is not allowed"stack: "Error↵    at new NavigationDuplicated (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js:2009:14)↵    at HTML5History.confirmTransition (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js:2125:18)↵    at HTML5History.transitionTo (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js:2069:8)↵    at HTML5History.push (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js:2400:10)↵    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js:2812:22)↵    at new Promise ()↵    at VueRouter.push (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js:2811:12)↵    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:204:26)↵    at Array.forEach ()↵    at Object.eval [as next] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:175:31)"**proto**: Error 
> > eval @ vue-router.esm.js:2086 
> > abort @ vue-router.esm.js:2117
> > confirmTransition @ vue-router.esm.js:2125
> > transitionTo @ vue-router.esm.js:2069
> > push @ vue-router.esm.js:2400
> > eval @ vue-router.esm.js:2812
> > push @ vue-router.esm.js:2811
> > eval @ cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:204
> > eval @ cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:175
> > next @ index.cjs.js:22426
> > eval @ index.cjs.js:20155
> > setTimeout (async)
> > AsyncObserver.scheduleEvent @ index.cjs.js:20153
> > AsyncObserver.next @ index.cjs.js:20142
> > QueryListener.raiseInitialEvent @ index.cjs.js:17098
> > QueryListener.onViewSnapshot @ index.cjs.js:17033
> > EventManager.listen @ index.cjs.js:16889
> > eval @ index.cjs.js:20004
> > eval @ index.cjs.js:1698
> > Promise.then (async)
> > AsyncQueue.enqueueInternal @ index.cjs.js:1696
> > AsyncQueue.enqueue @ index.cjs.js:1692
> > AsyncQueue.enqueueAndForget @ index.cjs.js:1639
> > FirestoreClient.listen @ index.cjs.js:20003
> > Query.onSnapshotInternal @ index.cjs.js:22432
> > Query.onSnapshot @ index.cjs.js:22413
> > oyunVeRakipTanimla @ cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:174
> > eval @ cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:155
> > Promise.then (async)
> > createGameRoom @ cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:154
> > newGame @ cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:133
> > invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1853
> > invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js:2178
> > original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js:6907

Where am I making mistakes?

What method should I follow to direct both users to the game page in real time?

Comment: Previous stackoverflow questions said that this error happens when you create a router link or attempt to push the router to a view that you are already in. if you're inside of `/game` and try to navigate to `/game` this error will pop up

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57837758/navigationduplicated-navigating-to-current-location-search-is-not-allowed) question here

Comment: Try doing `this.$router.push('/game')` or whatever you have the name of the physical route set to

Comment: The method you said didn't work. It gives the same error.
I am reviewing the resource you shared. @KevinHernandez

Comment: Try calling the method on vues next tick `this.$nextTick(() =>this.$router.push('/game'))`

Comment: I tried this method:`this.$nextTick(() =>this.$router.push('/game'))`.
I printed the name of the current page inside the `createGameAndOpponent` function:`console.log("Before going to the game page:"+this.$route.path);`
But sometimes it gives the result of "/game" although it is also on the Homepage. @KevinHernandez

Comment: Yeah that means the component is loaded before you call router.push something is causing your component to load prematurely

Comment: I updated the question details. I also shared the "Vue Router - index.js" details.You can review

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208248/discussion-between-kevin-hernandez-and-hibrit-usta).