# vue-router — Uncaught (in promise) Error: Redirected from "/login" to "/" via a navigation guard

Tags: vue.js, promise, vue-router

Why is vue-router giving me this error? To be clear, the login flow works as intended but I want to a) get rid of the errro and b) understand why the error is happening.

**Error:**

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Redirected from "/login" to "/" via a
> navigation guard.

**Login flow**

1. start logged out, but enter a URL that requires auth (i.e. anything besides "/login")
2. get redirected to "/login" (as expected).
3. login
4. successfully get redirected to starting Url from step #1, except with the above error.

**Login action:**

```js
doLogin({ commit }, loginData) {
  commit("loginStart");
  axiosClient
    .post("/jwt-auth/v1/token", {
      username: loginData.username,
      password: loginData.password,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      commit("loginStop", null);
      commit("setUserData", response.data);
      this.categories = airtableQuery.getTable("Categories");
      commit("setCategories", this.categories);
      this.locations = airtableQuery.getTable("Locations");
      commit("setLocations", this.locations);
      router.push("/"); // push to site root after authentication
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.response.data.message);
      commit("loginStop", error.response.data.message);
      commit("delUserData");
    });
},
```

**Router:**

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "Login",
    component: Login,
    meta: { requiresAuth: false },
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
    meta: { requiresAuth: true },
  },
];

let entryUrl = null;
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  let localStorageUserData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
  let storeUserData = state.getters.getUserData;
  let userData = localStorageUserData || storeUserData;
  let isAuthenticated = userData.token !== "" && userData.token !== undefined;
  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      if (to.name !== "Login" && to.name !== "Home") {
        entryUrl = to.fullPath;
      }
      next({ name: "Login" });
    } else if (entryUrl) {
      let url = entryUrl;
      entryUrl = null;
      next(url);
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Comment: Playground: https://jsfiddle.net/eyedean/m6zsugo5/18/

I used it to play around and get to my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65326844

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The error message is getting updated in the next version of vue-router. The error will read:

> Redirected when going from "/login" to "/" via a navigation guard

Somewhere in your code, after being redirected to "/login", you are redirecting back to "/". And vue-router is complaining about. You'll want to make sure you only have one redirect per navigation action.

Comment: thank you. Can you tell from my router `beforeEach` block how that double re-direct might be happening? The login action does a "push" -- so that's not really a redirect per se is it?

Comment: Jason- can you add more detail? Why do we need to make sure we only have one redirect, and how would you describe a "navigation action" so that I can chain a few redirects together?

Comment: @NathanStrutz something like `router.push("/someNewPage")` would be considered a navigation action, along with `to` and `next` in the navigation guards.

Comment: I doubt your explanation for [the code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/c69ff7bd60228fb79acd764c3fdae91015a49103/src/history/base.js#L206) isn't doing any such extra testing. According to [the docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) it's an intended use case. AFAICS this "error" is logged whenever a guard is redirecting by invoking `next()` with any new target. Logging an error here is wrong. A warning would be sufficient ...

Comment: not sure if I got that right but that's exactly my intention - to redirect in the navigation guard if the route is not permitted, but I'm getting this error. Aren't we allowed to redirect in the navigationGuard? How do we secure paths and redirect back to login if user tries to access the paths they are not allowed to? I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: @virus, I understand your confusion.  Double redirects are totally fine.  Read my answer below -- I hope it sheds some light on the fact that this is not a "redirect" error at all.

Comment: figured that out - that's not a problem actually. The redirect will happen anyway. The error just indicates to the caller code that the initial navigation was interrupted and instead of completing the initial navigation, it was redirected. That's sort of a way to tell "sorry man, you've asked to navigate, but we've redirected instead. Nothing personal.". The caller code is supposed to catch that and handle if needed (in my case I don't need to handle that and it's fine to ignore it).

Comment: The accepted answer is not exactly correct. You can have as many redirects as you want. Just make sure to catch the error if you don't want to see it in your console.
Also, catching the error is particularly important for when the navigation originated in an asynchronous context: leaving an unhandled error floating around can cause unexpected issues.

Comment: It might be helpful to ensure that it's not creating an infinite redirect because the referring page is then the redirect path. For me I was directing traffic based on authentication, and was getting an infinite loop. I ended up setting up a check in my router to ensure that the referring page wasn't the same as the destination page - from.name!='Login' in my case.

Answer (score 133):

I spent hours debugging this and got to the following results for the ugly `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Redirected when going from ...` Error.

Note that the error is not for the "redirect".  It's for the initial caller of the first navigation. Keep reading...

### It's by design. Why?

Read [this comment](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2881#issuecomment-520554378).

TL;DR: Let's say you are on page A, and click on a button to take you to page B (kinda like `method: goToB() { router.push('/B'); }` on page A).  But there is a [Navigation Guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) for page B, that sends you to page C.

This error is a way for letting that `goToB()` function know that the router hasn't been able to fulfill the desired task, and the user hasn't landed on `/B`.

### It's nasty, but informative

The biggest confusion here is that the redirect (landing on Page C) is, both:

- an **"expected"** outcome to you, the architect of the system. But, at the same time,
- an **"unexpected"** event to the caller of `goToB` in page A (i.e. `router.push`), who expects the router to go to page B.

That's why when it's popped as `Error`, it's confusing and frustrating to **"you"**, who looks at the system entirely and thinks nothing is wrong or erroneous!

### Urrrgh... So, what should I do?

#### Solution 1: Use `router-link` if you can

I ran into a case that `<router-link>` was working fine, but `router.push` was complaining.  (I think router-link internally suppresses such errors.)

#### Solution 2.1: Individual suppress errors on each `router.push` call

The `router.push` function is returning a `Promise` (as it can be considered, or will be, an asynchronous job).  All you need to do is to suppress any Error it might throw via

```js
router.push('/B').catch(() => {});
//     Add this: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

#### Solution 2.2: Augment Router.prototype.push to always suppress errors

If you think you have multiple instances of this, you can augment the `push` function on the `prototype` of the `Router` via [the snippet on the same comment](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2881#issuecomment-520554378) to apply this to all the `router.push` calls on the entire app.

The good news is it's giving you granularity level to choose which error you want to suppress (e.g. only `NavigationFailureTypes.redirected` ones, for example. The enum is [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/src/util/errors.js#L2))

If you are on TypeScript, be my guest on the conversion and typing https://gist.github.com/eyedean/ce6ab6a5108a1bd19ace64382144b5b0 :)

---

### Other tips:

1. Upgrade your `vue-router`!  Your case might be solved by the time you read this. (As they have a plan to do so, apparently.)
2. Make sure you are not forking or reaching to dead-end in your Navigation Guards, if you have multiple ones.  Follow them one by one and track them step by step.  Note that, double redirecting is fine (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62563439/2321594)), you just need to be double careful!
3. I also got a playground here: https://codepen.io/eyedean/pen/MWjmKjV You can start mimicking this to your need to figure out where your problem happens in the first place.

Comment: Thanks! Any way to catch the error on `next('/login')` in `router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => ...` ? `next('/login').catch(() => { })` gives Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined.

Comment: My flow is valid: landing on `/`, not signed in, redirect to `/login`, signin via ajax, redirect to `/`

Comment: @marius, As I said it is a "warning" most of the time.  It shouldn't be popped if you have exactly one redirection going on in every step.  But, probably if you put a breakpoint on where the error is thrown, you will see that you have nested redirects, not two isolated redirects. That's my guess.  And due to that, you will see this error -- it means that before the first redirect is fully finished, committed, and flushed, another redirect has occurred.

So, you can either ignore it, or silence it, or rewrite your code so that these two redirects happen in different stack-traces, not nested.

Comment: Basically what I've learned at this point is that the error caused by redirection in a navigation guard is intended behavior and should probably be left alone. I mean, in the projects that I've performed such redirections, the page that I redirect to does get rendered in the end. I think in my opinion, this alert should be reduced to a warning and not displayed as an error.

Comment: Great answer! Concerning 'Solution 2.1', i.e. `router.push('/B').catch(() => {});`, indeed, the exception is not uncaught anymore. Nonetheless, I find it annoying that my browser (Chrome) still gets paused: I would have like such a behavior only with uncaught exceptions...

Answer (score 23):

I had a similar error, but for an onboarding redirect in **.beforeEach**, which was resolved by replacing in the **.beforeEach** conditional logic:

```js
next({ name: "Onboarding" });
```

with

```js
router.push({ path: 'Onboarding' });
```

Comment: that seemed to work for me until I noticed that going back in browser stopped working. Watching route change stopped working, beforeRouteUpdate hook stopped working. The url changes, but things that must react to it don't react to it.

Comment: It seems like a working band-aid, but I really want to get a solution that relies on `next`, as it's the intended function to work with.

Answer (score 15):

This error is meant to inform the caller of `$router.push` that the navigation didn't go to where it was initially intended. If you expect a redirection you can safely ignore the error with the following code.

```js
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
const { isNavigationFailure, NavigationFailureType } = VueRouter

...

this.$router.push('/')
  .catch((e) => {
    if (!isNavigationFailure(e, NavigationFailureType.redirected)) {
        Promise.reject(e)
    }
  }
```

See https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2932 for a discussion regarding this issue.

Comment: I'm not super promise proficient, but if I chain a catch, for some reason Promise.reject(e) doesn't trigger the 2nd catch, but throw e instead does. Is there an obvious reason I'm missing?

Answer (score 10):

If your redirect is after a call to router.push('/someroute) then you can catch this error as router.push() is a promise and you can attach a catch to it as below

```js
$router.push('/somesecureroute')
.catch(error => {
   console.info(error.message)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me on application boot, during an authorization check I tried to push to '/auth' but that navigation was cancelled by another call to '/', which occurred just after mine.

So in the end I found that is possible to listen for readiness (https://router.vuejs.org/api/#isready) of vue-router using:

```js
await router.isReady()
```

or

```js
router.isReady().then(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, i thought it was config problem but it was not
You can try this code

```js
async doLogin({ commit, dispatch }, loginData) {
  commit("loginStart");
  let response = await axiosClient
  .post("/jwt-auth/v1/token", {
    username: loginData.username,
    password: loginData.password,
  })
  return dispacth('attempt', response) 
}

async attempt({ commit }, response) {
  try {
    commit("loginStop", null);
    commit("setUserData", response.data);
    this.categories = airtableQuery.getTable("Categories");
    commit("setCategories", this.categories);
    this.locations = airtableQuery.getTable("Locations");
    commit("setLocations", this.locations);
  }
  catch( (error) => {
    console.log(error.response.data.message);
    commit("loginStop", error.response.data.message);
    commit("delUserData");
  })
}
```

And in the component where doLogin action is called

```js
this.doLogin(this.loginData)
    .then( () => {
        this.$router.replace('/')
        .catch( error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    })
    .catch( e => {
        console.log(e)
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error. This error created by `router.push("/");` row - it trying to say you that pushing to home was interrupted by redirection in navigation guard.
But actually, it's not an error because it is an expected behaviour.

I made ignoring of such errors by the following way:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: _routes,
});

/**
 * Do not throw an exception if push is rejected by redirection from navigation guard
 */
const originalPush = router.push;
router.push = function push(location, onResolve, onReject) {
    if (onResolve || onReject) {
        return originalPush.call(this, location, onResolve, onReject);
    }
    return originalPush.call(this, location).catch((err) => {
        let reg = new RegExp('^Redirected when going from "[a-z_.\\/]+" to "[a-z_.\\/]+" via a navigation guard.$');
        if (reg.test(err.message)) {
            // If pushing interrupted because of redirection from navigation guard - ignore it.
            return Promise.resolve(false);
        }
        // Otherwise throw error
        return Promise.reject(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: You can do `if (Router.isNavigationFailure(err, Router.NavigationFailureType.redirected)) {` instead of using RegEx `reg`.  Read my answer for more details. I have put the link to my gist there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue triggered by two specific pages, for the two pages that were being redirected due to a login:

```
if (isAdmin){
   router.push({name: 'page'}).catch(error=>{
          console.info(error.message)}) 
else...
```

otherwise everyone else who is a regular user gets pushed to a different page using "router.push"

ONLY on the redirects that were throwing the original error/warning. Suppressing the warning as suggested in an earlier comment:

```
if (!to.matched.length) console.warn('no match');
  next()
```

allowed for users to sign in and access pages without proper permissions.

Catching the errors appears to be the way to go, per the suggestion of: kissu

Answer (score 0):

For me, the reason for the error was the issue with the A label. I tried to replace A label and resolved the problem

```
    <a href="#/" ><span class="topbar-user-arrowspan class="topbar-user-logout" @click="logTheServer">***</span></a>
```

changer

```
    <div><span class="topbar-user-arrowspan class="topbar-user-logout" @click="logTheServer">***</span></div>
```

```
`
LogTheServer(){

this.$router.push('/manage/serverRegistration?isCancellation=truethis')
}`
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem only on my iPad.
I have fixed it going to safari settings and disabled the setting "disable all cookies".
I hope that this help you.
Dario