# Redirecting twice in a single Vue navigation

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In my Vue app, a user's homepage depends on their role. To ensure that a user is shown the correct homepage, I use this navigation guard:

```
export default (to, from, next) => {
  const authService = getAuthService()

  if (to.path === '/') {
    // if they've requested the home page, send them to 
    // different pages depending on their role
    if (authService.isUser()) {
      next({ name: 'events' })

    } else if (authService.isAdmin()) {
      next({ name: 'admin-events' })

    } else {
      next()
    }
  }
}
```

Then when a user successfully logs in, I redirect them to `'/'`

```
  this.$router.push({path: '/'))
```

and the nav guard above redirects them to their role-specific homepage. However, redirecting twice in the course of a single navigation action [is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62231211/2648) and causes the following error to appear in the console when the second redirection occurs (in the nav guard)
`

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Redirected when going from `"/login"` to `"/"` via a navigation guard.

Another case in my app where this happens is the 404 component that handles attempts to access non-existent routes, i.e.

1. User attempts to access invalid route
2. 404 component redirects back to `'/'`
3. Nav guard redirects to user-specific homepage, causing an error

Is there a way I can support these use cases without redirecting twice?

Comment: Which kind of guards you used? beforeEach? afterEach? or others?

Comment: And it will be better put `const authService = getAuthService()` into the following line=`if (to.path === '/') {`; because if `to.path !== '/'`,  **getAuthService** is not neccessary.

Answer (score 12):

**tldr: `vm.$router.push(route)` is a promise and needs to `.catch(e=>gotCaught(e))` errors.**

---

**This will be changed in the next [major](https://github.com/posva/rfcs/blob/router/navigation-failures/active-rfcs/0000-router-navigation-failures.md#redirections)@4**

---

Currently@3 errors are not distinguished whether they are `NavigationFailures` or `regular Errors`.

The naive expected route after `vm.$router.push(to)` should be `to`. Thus one can expect some failure message once there was a redirect. **Before patching** router.push to be a promise **the error was *ignored* silently**.
The current solution is to antipattern a `.catch(...)` onto every push, or to anticipate the change in design and wrap it to expose the failure as result.

Future plans have it to put those informations into the result:

```
  let failure = await this.$router.push(to);
  if(failure.type == NavigationFailureType[type]){}
  else{}
```

---

Imo this error is just by [design](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/0eaae3a906b2123cc14536280964307d4b666de3/src/history/base.js#L190) and should be handled:

```
hook(route, current, (to: any) => { ... abort(createNavigationRedirectedError(current, route)) ...}
```

So basically if `to` contains a redirect it is an error, which kinda is equal to using `vm.$router.push` into a guard.

To ignore the unhandled error behaviour one can pass an empty onComplete (breaks in future releases):

```
vm.$router.push(Route, ()=>{})
```

or wrap it in `try .. catch`

```
try {

  await this.$router.push("/")
} catch {

}
```

which prevents the [promise to throw uncaught](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/0eaae3a906b2123cc14536280964307d4b666de3/src/index.js#L155).

---

to support this without redirecting twice means you put the guard to your exit:

```
let path = "/"
navguard({path}, undefined, (to)=>this.$router.push(to||path))
```

which will polute every component redirecting to **home**

---

btw the `router-link` component [uses an empty onComplete](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/0eaae3a906b2123cc14536280964307d4b666de3/src/components/link.js#L81)

---

[Assumption that redirecting twice is not allowed is wrong.](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2881#issuecomment-520554378)

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution might be as follows:

Let's assume that `/` route points to `HomeComponent`.

1. User navigates to `/`
2. In `created` lifecyle hook, get the `authService` and check user's permission
3. 2.a. If it's a user -> navigate them to `/events` route + replace the history
4. 2.b. If it's an administrator -> navigate them to `/admin-events` route + replace the history
5. Add guards for each `/events` route so a user without permission won't see `/admin-events`, etc

*Bonus*: You are now able to add a message to `HomeComponent` saying "redirecting you to Events page" or "redirecting you to Administrator Events page" (if needed).

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution might be;

1. Adding a query string parameter to define that user coming to the `/` route after login. Like `?fromLogin=1`
2. Adding `beforeEnter` hook to the `/` route and attaching the navigation guard check on that hook.
3. If user coming to the `/` route from login, redirecting them to the role based page.