# Nuxt Middleware with Firebase and FirebaseUI: Error: Redirected when going from "/anything" to "/login" via a navigation guard

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, firebaseui

Nuxt SSR app using FirebaseUI to handle auth flows. Logging in and out works perfectly. When I add Middleware to check auth state and redirect if not logged in I get this error:

> Error: Redirected when going from "/list-cheatsheets" to "/login" via a navigation guard.

middleware/auth.js

```js
export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
    // If the user is not authenticated
    if (!store.state.user) {
      return redirect('/login')
    }
  }
```

There is absolutely no other redirecting that I can find in the app....

I have been digging and trying things for hours. Others who get this error that I have found aren't using Nuxt and none of those solutions work.

Comment: looks like someone created a bounty for this here: https://lazyfox.io/task/JjV/nuxt-middleware-with-firebase-and-firebaseui-error-redirected-when-going-from-an

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is a bounty one cannot mark it duplicate thus following up is a copy of my answer at [Redirecting twice in a single Vue navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62512168/redirecting-twice-in-a-single-vue-navigation/62563439#62563439)

---

**tldr: `vm.$router.push(route)` is a promise and needs to `.catch(e=>gotCaught(e))` errors.**

---

**This will be changed in the next [major](https://github.com/posva/rfcs/blob/router/navigation-failures/active-rfcs/0000-router-navigation-failures.md#redirections)@4**

---

Currently@3 errors are not distinguished whether they are `NavigationFailures` or `regular Errors`.

The naive expected route after `vm.$router.push(to)` should be `to`. Thus one can expect some failure message once there was a redirect. **Before patching** router.push to be a promise **the error was *ignored* silently**.
The current solution is to antipattern a `.catch(...)` onto every push, or to anticipate the change in design and wrap it to expose the failure as result.

Future plans have it to put those informations into the result:

```
  let failure = await this.$router.push(to);
  if(failure.type == NavigationFailureType[type]){}
  else{}
```

---

Imo this error is just by [design](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/0eaae3a906b2123cc14536280964307d4b666de3/src/history/base.js#L190) and should be handled:

```
hook(route, current, (to: any) => { ... abort(createNavigationRedirectedError(current, route)) ...}
```

So basically if `to` contains a redirect it is an error, which kinda is equal to using `vm.$router.push` into a guard.

To ignore the unhandled error behaviour one can pass an empty onComplete (breaks in future releases):

```
vm.$router.push(Route, ()=>{})
```

or wrap it in `try .. catch`

```
try {

  await this.$router.push("/")
} catch {

}
```

which prevents the [promise to throw uncaught](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/0eaae3a906b2123cc14536280964307d4b666de3/src/index.js#L155).

---

to support this without redirecting twice means you put the guard to your exit:

```
let path = "/"
navguard({path}, undefined, (to)=>this.$router.push(to||path))
```

which will polute every component redirecting to **home**

---

btw the `router-link` component [uses an empty onComplete](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/0eaae3a906b2123cc14536280964307d4b666de3/src/components/link.js#L81)

---

[Assumption that redirecting twice is not allowed is wrong.](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2881#issuecomment-520554378)

Comment: I appreciate your response and indeed had seen your answer. This doesn't seem to apply to Nuxt Middleware however. I could be wrong. But I'm unable to access `this` from middleware. Any thoughts on how to handle this from global nuxt middleware? Thank you.

Comment: @Brad the parameter passed to middleware is your `this`, above i explain that your error is due to redirect. Basically you route(1) to your cheatsheets but as you are not authenticated you get rerouted(2) to login. Thus your first step throws.

Comment: I do understand that the problem lies in the double redirection. I guess what is really messing with me is that this seems to be a very basic task (navigation guards) and middleware in nuxt is the "nuxt" way to do it. Why am I not seeing much more on the web about this issue when it would seem to affect basically all nuxt users? Also, I'm at a loss as to how to in this instance fix it in a reasonable and practical way. Because I want to guard the routes without errors and without doing it in each file. I'm new to nuxt and fairly new to Vue so I'm not having success with your suggestions.thanks

Comment: @Brad i dont know how you initialize your route transition, all you tell is that you use a redirect, and by default using a `nuxt-link` extends from `router-link` which will silent out redirection errors. your issue is where you start your routing which expects your final route to be `cheatsheets` but instead gets `login` - from your provided information i cannot tell what you are doing different but i can guess you do something different. I am willing to help you. Pls show us how you start the routing ;)

Comment: I truly appreciate your kindness and willingness to help. I'm not certain how to respond about how I start the routing. In Nuxt the router is by default magically managed and I have the above code as "middleware" which taps into the router.

Comment: @Brad it is no magic, so either you click a link, you router.push or you type an url. Maybe make a page add a nuxt-link to cheatsheets, run dev, check if error still shows. i bet it will not - if it does then there is some weird created hook with an uncaught router.push on your cheatsheet page, also comment out middleware property in optionblock

Comment: I'm having this exact problem when following the basic middleware guide: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/middleware#named-middleware
The basic idea is that any page that does not pass the test (authenticated === true) would redirect to `/login`, including typing in a url. Using router-link does not apply here. I am also baffled how this basic task seems to not work for us.

Comment: @JoeSadoski is it not working or just raising? In the latter proper error handling should solve it.