# Vue Router "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Redirected when going from "/home" to "/login" via a navigation guard."

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I'm using Laravel as a backend server and Vue for the frontend of my application. Now, I have an issue with logging out of the application. I have created a route in Vue as follows:

```
import { RouteConfig } from 'vue-router';
import store from '@/store';

const routes: Array<RouteConfig> = [
  {
    path: '/logout',
    name: 'Logout',
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      store.dispatch('login/logout');
      next('/login');
    },
  },
];

export default routes;
```

and in the store I have the following action to actually perform the logout:

```
import { Commit, GetterTree } from 'vuex';
import userClient from '@/modules/core/api/userClient';
import { LoginState } from './types';

const namespaced = true;
const state: LoginState = {
  userToken: null,
  user: {},
  role: {},
  authentication: {},
};

const getters: GetterTree<LoginState, any> = {};

const actions = {
  async logout({ commit }: { commit: Commit }) {
    await userClient.logout();
    commit('clearUser');
  },
};

const mutations = {
  clearUser(state: any) {
    state.userToken = null;
    state.user = null;
    state.role = null;
    state.authentication = null;
  },
};

export default {
  namespaced,
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};
```

The Laravel backend then destroys the Cookie in which the JWT is stored.

Now when I navigate to the `/logout` route via `this.$router.push('/logout')` I get the following error in the browser:

```
vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2062 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Redirected when going from "/home" to "/login" via a navigation guard.
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Actually, it's a new feature of the vue-router library. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64808960/7662112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the navigation guard properly. According to the Vue-Router [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html):

> *As the name suggests, the navigation guards provided by vue-router are primarily used to guard navigations either by redirecting it or canceling it.*

Navigation guards are not appropriate for what you are trying to achieve. Why not just dispatch the logout action directly from the button/link?

The logout process should be pretty straight-forward.

- User presses `logout` button/link.
- The Laravel backend then destroys the Cookie in which the JWT is stored (in your case).
- The user is then routed to the login page.

There's no need for a logout (`/logout`) route.

In that case, the following flow would probably be more appropriate for your use case

#### ComponentWithLogoutButtonOrLink.vue

```html
<template>
....
<button @click="handleLogout">logout</button>
</template>
```

```js
methods: {
  handleLogout() {
   this.$store.dispatch('login/logout');
  }
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what's wrong with using next('/login')? As the cited snipped says "primarily used to guard navigations either by redirecting it or canceling it" - this is exactly the redirection, or is it? I'm just trying to understand how this works as typically you would call next('/login') in the guard to redirect if user is logged out and is not permitted to visit a specific page. So why would it through in the OP's case and what is the difference when you guard the paths - in both cases it looks technically the same - you are redirecting a user to "login". What I'm missing here?

Comment: Hi, @virus, there's nothing wrong with using next('/login'). The OP is using the navigation guard, not as a check to see if a route is invalid (e.g when auth token has expired, or unauthorised access), but to dispatch a logout action. In your case, using next('login') would come after the token has been checked. An excellent example can be seen here https://css-tricks.com/protecting-vue-routes-with-navigation-guards/.

Comment: Thanks @Tony. I guess my confusion came from the fact that the redirection throws the error anyway - however as it appeared, the error doesn't prevent the redirection and just indicates that the initially intended navigation "failed"  because of the redirection itself (by rejecting promise under the hood). So in this case the error in the log doesn't really mean that something bad happened which makes sense I guess. I just though I was doing something wrong and need to fix that error somehow - never saw it before and it seems it was introduced in some recent Vue Router library.

Comment: This is the way to go! Get rid of an unnecessary route "/logout". Thanks!