# "Redirected from {route} to {another route} via a navigation guard." after doing a second redirect

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm having a trouble doing a redirection with my code.

I have something like this:

`store/auth.js:`

```
async login(credentials) {
  const user = await api.post(credentials);
  if (user.role === 'someRole') {
     router.push({name: 'warehouses'});
  }
}
```

I redirect the user to warehouses, and this is good, but when I try to redirect the user again to their own warehouse:

`warehouses.vue`

```
  async beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    const user = store.getters.getUser;
    const warehouses = await api.get('warehouses');
    const userWarehouse = getWarehouseOwner(user, warehouses);
    
    if (userWarehouse) {
      next({name: 'warehouse', params: {id: userWareHouse }})';
    }
  }
```

Then I'm getting an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Navigation cancelled from "/login" to "/warehouses" with a new navigation.
```

I read about this specific error and it looks like is [unsupported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62223195/vue-router-uncaught-in-promise-error-redirected-from-login-to-via-a/62231211#62231211). How can I get around this error? Is there a way I can perform the second redirection?