# Redirected when going from to via navigation guard

Tags: vue-router

I'm trying to protect my Vue components using the Vue router authentication guard.
Case scenario: unauthenticated user lands on home page ("/" route) and he's trying to access "/profile", but that's a private component, so he'll be redirected by the vue router to "/auth/profile", so he'll authenticate and then the Auth component will redirect the user to the "/profile" component, because he got its path in the URL.

That's my guard

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.private)) {
    if (!store.getters.getUser) {
      //console.log("PRIVATE - NOT authenticated");
      next({ path: "/auth" + `${to.path}` });
    } else {
      //console.log("PRIVATE - authenticated");
      next();
    }
  } else {
    //console.log("NOT PRIVATE");
    next();
  }
});
```

Everything works as expected, but I get an error and it's annoying

```
Redirected when going from "/" to "/profile" via a navigation guard.
```

Comment: Seems to be a bug, which was fixed on version 3.3.1. Otherwise try to delete your node_modules folder and package-lock.json file and run `npm install` again.

Comment: @gurumaxi I just tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: You are being redirected multiple times

Comment: You aren't doing anything wrong, see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64808960/7662112

Comment: Here's the link that @gurumaxi is talking about of the `3.3.1` bugfix: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/CHANGELOG.md#331-2020-05-27

Comment: @fredrivett I just updated my vue-router to the latest version (3.4.9) but the problem still persist

Comment: @johnykes upgrading seemed to do the job for me, try deleting your `node_modules` and `yarn.lock`, reinstalling, reloading your server and seeing if the error still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by replacing

```
 next({ name: "Onboarding" });
```

with

```
router.push({ path: 'Onboarding' });
```

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your code, after being redirected to `"/profile"`, you are being redirected back to `"/"`. And that is what the vue-router is complaining about.

So the problem resides in being redirected multiple times per action.

You'll want to make sure you only have one redirect per navigation action.

Comment: Well I'm not sure how to change that. For example, if an unauthenticated user tried to access /profile, then he will be redirected to /auth/profile, so the app will know that after the user will authenticate, he will be redirected to /profile, because that's what he was trying to access. That's why I have a double redirect.How should I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Reduce vue-router version to `3.0.7`, or
follow code into your `app.js` or `index.js`, which one you import `vue-router`
example:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

const originalPush = VueRouter.prototype.push
VueRouter.prototype.push = function push(location, onResolve, onReject) {undefined
if (onResolve || onReject) return originalPush.call(this, location, onResolve, onReject)
return originalPush.call(this, location).catch(err => err)
}

Vue.use(VueRouter);
...

#code
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be because your other component (the one you are pointing to) is redirecting you back.