# Vue router, Error: Redirected * to * via a navigation guard

Tags: vue-router

Access /dashboard/profile get error

vue-router.esm.js:1958 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Redirected when going from “/home” to “/dashboard” via a navigation guard.

```
// router.ts
const routes: Array<RouteConfig> = [
    {path: '/', redirect: {name: 'Home'}},
    {path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: Home},
    {
        path: '/dashboard', component: () => import('../views/Dashboard.vue'),
        meta: {isLogin: true},
        children: [
            {path: '', component: () => import('../views/Dash/Certificate/index.vue'), meta: {isViewer: true},
            {path: 'profile', component: () => import('../views/Dash/ProfileComponent.vue')},
        ]
    },
];


//guard
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const profilePath = "/dashboard/profile";
    if (!to.matched.some(res => res.meta.isLogin)) {
        return next();
    }

    // isNotLogin
    if (!localStorage['currentUser'])
        return next({path: "/", query: {redirect: to.fullPath}});

    // isLogin
    if (to.matched.some(res => res.meta?.isViewer)) {
        viewService.isCertificateViewer ? next() : next({path: profilePath})
    } else next()
});
```

Comment: were you able to solve this? getting the same error now

Comment: also wondering if you were able to solve this...

Answer (score 3):

I spent four hours trying to solve this same problem. This is the article I found that explained where the error was coming from: [vue-router — Uncaught (in promise) Error: Redirected from "/login" to "/" via a navigation guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62223195/vue-router-uncaught-in-promise-error-redirected-from-login-to-via-a?rq=1)

Imagine you have routes a, b, and c. The user is on route a. They then click a link that is supposed to send them to route b. We then catch that in a route guard and redirect them to route c. This makes sense to the developer because there was a reason to redirect to route c, but the people in charge have decided that is a jarring experience to the user, and we shouldn't call route redirects in ways that don't make sense to the user.

tl;dr the problem is with how you initially direct to a route. Instead of `router.push('/b')` do `router.push('/b').catch((e) => e);` Just suppress the error and everything will work great.