# vue-router - Navigation cancelled from "/" to "/password" with a new navigation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Trying to navigate to password page, vue-router throwing this error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Navigation cancelled from "/" to "/password" with a new navigation.
```

Navigating to password page is successfully redirected but not sure why this error is throwing. I didnt observe this error before.

Vue router version:
**vue-router@3.3.4**

On click on a button doing `this.$router.push({name: 'password', query: {username: this.username}})`

In router/index.js

```
{
path: '/',
component: loginComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: '/',
    alias: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: () => import('../views/email.vue')
  },
  {
    path: 'password',
    name: 'password',
    component: () => import('../views/password.vue')
  }
]
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62231211/8482368

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vue-router — Uncaught (in promise) Error: Redirected from "/login" to "/" via a navigation guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62223195/vue-router-uncaught-in-promise-error-redirected-from-login-to-via-a)

Comment: It sounds like you redirect twice to "/password" page, I've checked the source code, this error message being throw only if on-going navigation is not current one, and on-going one will be early cancelled.

Answer (score 9):

I recently got the same error. this is happening because vue router can't redirect twice (that means you can't redirect in a redirected route). this is mentioned in the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards)

> Make sure that the next function is called exactly once in any given pass through the navigation guard. It can appear more than once, but only if the logical paths have no overlap, otherwise the hook will never be resolved or produce errors.

I have a workaround for it which is to create a hidden `vue-route` component with the route you want to redirect to and then click.

example:

```
<router-link ref="redirect" :to="$route.query.redirect ? $route.query.redirect : '/'"></router-link>
```

and when you want to redirect (maybe in your case after the user enters the password) you can just trigger a click event on this link

```
this.$refs.redirect.$el.click()
```

Answer (score 6):

You should add a `catch()` to catch such errors:

```js
this.$router.push({
  name: 'password', 
  query: {
    username: this.username
  }
}).catch();
```

More information is available in the [VueRouter documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html).

Comment: Works great for me... Vue2/VueRouter3/Nuxt2

Answer (score 2):

Vue Router also provides a method called `isNavigationFailure` to identify the error:

```
import { isNavigationFailure, NavigationFailureType } from 'vue-router'

// trying to access the admin page
router.push('/admin').catch(failure => {
  if (isNavigationFailure(failure, NavigationFailureType.redirected)) {
    // show a small notification to the user
    showToast('Login in order to access the admin panel')
  }
})
```

More info [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-failures.html#detecting-navigation-failures).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to approach this is not catching and ignoring, but rather debugging and checking why the navigation is cancelled.

If you're navigating to the same route, you should check why.