# Is there a way to force vue router to redirect more than once?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I have a view for a route, let's say "form/:step", that reads and controls the route parameter "step".
I want to be able to go to said view without specifying the step, and then, based on a set of rules, I set the step parameter with:

`this.$router.replace({ params: { step } })` 
When I navigate to this view through a click, everything is ok.
But if I use programmatic navigation (push method) to go to this route, then the replace method fails with:

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Navigation cancelled from "/form" to "/form/step-1" with a new navigation.`

Is there a way to force this? I've tried catching the error, but that does not force the redirect.

Comment: Would this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66005494/10975709

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide really what your route need to be.
But for me, what i understand is your params is optionnal so you just have to add a `?`.

```
{
    path: '/form/:step?',
},
```

The params is now optionnal and you can define a setup or not!