# Navigation cancelled in console, what could be wrong?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I logout from a page it calls a following error: (Uncaught (in promise) Error: Navigation cancelled from "/recenzije" to "/prijava" with a new navigation). Is this maybe because i have duplicated routes when user is not logged in or what?
Here is my app.vue code (I think there is a problem because when I remove it the problem disappears):

```
if(currentRoute.meta.needsUser){
        router.push({name:'prijava'});
    }
```

And there is my logout function in a different vue (recenzije.vue):

```
signOut() {
        firebase.auth().signOut().then(() =>{
        this.$router.push({ name: 'prijava' })
        })
    },
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And what appened if you use **path** instead of **name** in your push function ?

Comment: The same thing happens

Comment: Hava a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62223195/vue-router-uncaught-in-promise-error-redirected-from-login-to-via-a/62231211#62231211