# How do I suppress errors in vue router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm getting this error in a VueJS application: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Navigation cancelled from "/" to "/dashboard" with a new navigation.` Its been documents in SO before
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62223195/vue-router-uncaught-in-promise-error-redirected-from-login-to-via-a) and I've seen another article explaining it's due to the OAuth library I am using, making 2 calls thus causing a redirect.

I can't figure out how to suppress the error in my situation, the other answers use `router.push()`, i'm using a function in `beforeEnter`.

I've tried using: Try/Accept and catch (but not sure where to put them):

```
   try {
          next("/dashboard");
        } catch (err) {
          throw new Error(`Problem handling something: ${err}.`);
        }
```

**How do I suppress the error?**

My Router:

```
export default new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "Landing",
      component: Landing,
      meta: {
        title: "Landing",
      },
      beforeEnter: loginRedirectDashboard,
    },
})
```

Router Guard (beforeEnter)

```
function loginRedirectDashboard(to, from, next) {
  const authService = getInstance();
  authService.$watch("loading", (loading) => {
    if (loading === false) {
      if (to.path === "/") {
          next("/dashboard");
           } else {
          next();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Update:

`instance()` code

```
import Vue from "vue";
import createAuth0Client from "@auth0/auth0-spa-js";

/** Define a default action to perform after authentication */
const DEFAULT_REDIRECT_CALLBACK = () =>
  window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, window.location.pathname);

let instance;

/** Returns the current instance of the SDK */
export const getInstance = () => instance;

/** Creates an instance of the Auth0 SDK. If one has already been created, it returns that instance */
export const useAuth0 = ({
  onRedirectCallback = DEFAULT_REDIRECT_CALLBACK,
  redirectUri = window.location.origin,
  ...options
}) => {
  if (instance) return instance;

  // The 'instance' is simply a Vue object
  instance = new Vue({
    data() {
      return {
        loading: true,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: {},
        auth0Client: null,
        popupOpen: false,
        error: null,
        permission: null,
      };
    },
    methods: {
      /** Authenticates the user using a popup window */
      async loginWithPopup(options, config) {
        this.popupOpen = true;

        try {
          await this.auth0Client.loginWithPopup(options, config);
          this.user = await this.getUserWithMeta(); //await this.auth0Client.getUser();
          this.isAuthenticated = await this.auth0Client.isAuthenticated();
          this.error = null;
          this.permission = await this.permissionLevels();
        } catch (e) {
          this.error = e;
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          console.error(e);
        } finally {
          this.popupOpen = false;
        }

        this.user = await this.auth0Client.getUser();
        this.isAuthenticated = true;
      },
      /** Handles the callback when logging in using a redirect */
      async handleRedirectCallback() {
        this.loading = true;
        try {
          await this.auth0Client.handleRedirectCallback();
          this.user = await this.getUserWithMeta(); //await this.auth0Client.getUser();
          this.isAuthenticated = true;
          this.error = null;
          this.permission = await this.permissionLevels();
        } catch (e) {
          this.error = e;
        } finally {
          this.loading = false;
        }
      },
      /** Authenticates the user using the redirect method */
      loginWithRedirect(o) {
        return this.auth0Client.loginWithRedirect(o);
      },
      /** Returns all the claims present in the ID token */
      getIdTokenClaims(o) {
        return this.auth0Client.getIdTokenClaims(o);
      },
      /** Returns the access token. If the token is invalid or missing, a new one is retrieved */
      getTokenSilently(o) {
        return this.auth0Client.getTokenSilently(o);
      },
      /** Gets the access token using a popup window */

      async getUserWithMeta() {
        var userObject = await this.auth0Client.getUser();
        if (userObject != null) {
          var namespace = '********';
          var extractUserMeta = userObject[namespace];
          delete userObject[namespace];
          userObject.userInfo = extractUserMeta;
          return userObject;
        }
      },

      async permissionLevels(o) {
        if (this.isAuthenticated) {
          const jwtToken = await this.auth0Client.getTokenSilently(o);
          var base64Url = jwtToken.split(".")[1];
          var base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, "+").replace(/_/g, "/");
          var jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(
            atob(base64)
              .split("")
              .map(function(c) {
                return "%" + ("00" + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
              })
              .join("")
          );
          return JSON.parse(jsonPayload).permissions;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      },

      getTokenWithPopup(o) {
        return this.auth0Client.getTokenWithPopup(o);
      },
      /** Logs the user out and removes their session on the authorization server */
      logout(o) {
        delete localStorage.authToken;
        return this.auth0Client.logout(o);
      },
    },
    /** Use this lifecycle method to instantiate the SDK client */
    async created() {
      // Create a new instance of the SDK client using members of the given options object
      this.auth0Client = await createAuth0Client({
        ...options,
        client_id: options.clientId,
        redirect_uri: redirectUri,
      });

      try {
        // If the user is returning to the app after authentication..
        if (
          window.location.search.includes("code=") &&
          window.location.search.includes("state=")
        ) {
          // handle the redirect and retrieve tokens
          const { appState } = await this.auth0Client.handleRedirectCallback();

          this.error = null;

          // Notify subscribers that the redirect callback has happened, passing the appState
          // (useful for retrieving any pre-authentication state)
          onRedirectCallback(appState);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        this.error = e;
      } finally {
        // Initialize our internal authentication state
        this.isAuthenticated = await this.auth0Client.isAuthenticated();
        this.user = await this.getUserWithMeta(); //await this.auth0Client.getUser();
        this.loading = false;
        this.permission = await this.permissionLevels();
      }
    },
  });

  return instance;
};

// Create a simple Vue plugin to expose the wrapper object throughout the application
export const Auth0Plugin = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.prototype.$auth = useAuth0(options);
  },
};
```

Comment: Try adding `&& to.path !== '/dashboard'` to your `if` statement

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't work :(. Spent hours trying different combinations!

Comment: Does your dashboard have anything that would be point back to "/".

Comment: @jgetner I have removed every known instance of "/' in my project. From my research it looks like an issue with the OAuth library I am using - so at this point I just want to suppress the error. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Can you please share `getInstance()` code?