# Vue.js - NavigationDuplicated with new path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, router

I need help with **Vue.js** and the **NavigationDuplicated** error. I am developing a web application where I allow the user to navigate among different pages.

I get "NavigationDuplicated" error even though I am not pushing the same web page. Specifically, the error I get is:

> *message: "Navigating to current location ("/faq/new") is not allowed", name: "NavigationDuplicated", ...*

My router code is the following:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

import HomeView from "../views/HomeView.vue";
import KBView from "../views/KBView.vue";
import FaqDetailView from "../views/FaqDetailView.vue";
import NewFaqView from "../views/NewFaqView.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: HomeView
  },
  {
    path: "/kb",
    name: "Knowledge Base",
    component: KBView
  },
  {
    path: "/faq/:id",
    name: "Faq details",
    component: FaqDetailView
  },
  {
    path: "/faq/new",
    name: "New faq",
    component: NewFaqView
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});

export default router;
```

In each View, there is a button that is redirecting to another View. For example, once a button is clicked, is executed the following code:

```
this.$router.push({ name: "Knowledge Base" });
```

```
this.$router.push({ name: "New faq" })
```

I get the error with, for example, the following history of routes:

1. *localhost:8080/#/kb*
2. *localhost:8080/#/faq/new*
3. *localhost:8080/#/kb*
4. *localhost:8080/#/faq/new* ---> Here i get the NavigationDuplicated error

In this pic, you can see the history of routes registered by Vue extension for Chrome: [Routes history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVyVT.png)

Could you help me in understanding why I get the "NavigationDuplicated" error? How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here explanations and solutions [first](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2872) and [second](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2881), also you can check [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/handling-navigationduplicated-error/73275/3) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57837758/navigationduplicated-navigating-to-current-location-search-is-not-allowed).

Basically just catch and ignore that message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read the links but they do not answer to my question. If you read carefully my history of routes, you see that I get "NavigationDuplucated" when routing from _.../kb_ to _.../faq/new_. In addition, I would like to find a resolution rather than ignoring the error.

Comment: @NicolaMassarenti which version of vue-router are you using?

Comment: I could not reproduce your error and so neither main contributor of vue-router [check](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/150) many people already complained about this and about unexpected navigation errors like yours for now only way to handle this error is to catch it `changePage(){ this.$router.push({ name: "f n" }).catch((error) => {//log error}); },`

Comment: also you can reference [this](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/150#issuecomment-610056845), as router Promise based you can await answer, also in same thread you can find ways to handle navigation errors globally but they have own drawbacks sometimes

Comment: also little note that better add component in routing like this: `{
            path: '/page',
            name: 'page',
            component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: name_that_displayed_when_component_loaded */ "path/to/Component.vue")
        },` so this component will be imported only when user follows link