# Real-time search engine with VueJS and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am doing the search engine section in VueJS and Laravel, but I have a problem that does not allow me to advance in the other sections. The search engine opens and everything but when I write it only sends the first letter or 2 but not all of them like this in this image:

[image of the data you send](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auaDc.png)

[the data that I write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1KRC.png)

After that it shows me the following error in console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/search?q=th"
```

Now showing my search engine code:

```
<template>
  <div class="form_MCycW">
    <form autocomplete="off" @sumbit.prevent>
      <label class="visuallyhidden" for="search">Search</label>

      <div class="field_2KO5E">
        <input id="search" ref="input" v-model.trim="query" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search for a movie, tv show or person..." @keyup="goToRoute" @blur="unFocus">

        <button v-if="showButton" type="button" aria-label="Close" @click="goBack">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="15" height="15" viewBox="0 0 15 15"><g fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="1.5"><path d="M.75.75l13.5 13.5M14.25.75L.75 14.25"/></g></svg>
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapState } from 'vuex';

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        query: this.$route.query.q ? this.$route.query.q : ''
      }
    },

    computed: {
       showButton() {
           return this.$route.name === 'search';
       },

       ...mapState({
         search: state => state.event.fromPage
       })
     },

     mounted() {
       this.$refs.input.focus();
     },

     methods: {
       goToRoute() {
         if (this.query) {
           this.$router.push({
             name: 'search',
             query: { q: this.query },
           });
         } else {
           this.$router.push({
             path: this.fromPage,
           });
         }
       },

       goBack() {
         this.query = '';

         this.$router.push({
           path: '/',
         });
       },

       unFocus (e) {
         if (this.$route.name !== 'search') {
           const target = e.relatedTarget;

           if (!target || !target.classList.contains('search-toggle')) {
             this.query = '';
             this.$store.commit('closeSearch');
           } 
         }
       }
     }
   }
</script>
```

This is the other section of the search engine:

```
<template>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="listing">
      <div class="listing__head"><h2 class="listing__title">{{ title }}</h2></div>
      <div class="listing__items">
        <div class="card" v-for="(item, index) in data.data" :key="index">
          <router-link :to="{ name: 'show-serie', params: { id: item.id }}" class="card__link">
            <div class="card__img lazyloaded"><img class="lazyload image_183rJ" :src="'/_assets/img/covers/posters/' + item.poster" :alt="item.name"></div>
            <h2 class="card__name">{{ item.name }}</h2>
            <div class="card__rating">
              <div class="card__stars"><div :style="{width: item.rate * 10 + '%'}"></div></div>
              <div class="card__vote">{{ item.rate }}</div>
            </div>
          </router-link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>
<script>
  import { mapState } from 'vuex';
  let fromPage = '/';

  export default {
    name: "search",

    metaInfo: {
       bodyAttrs: {
        class: 'page page-search'
       }
    },

    computed: {
      ...mapState({
        data: state => state.search.data,
        loading: state => state.search.loading
      }),

      query() {
        return this.$route.query.q ? this.$route.query.q : '';
      },

      title() {
        return this.query ? `Results For: ${this.query}` : '';
      },
    },

    async asyncData ({ query, error, redirect }) {
      try {
        if (query.q) {
          this.$store.dispatch("GET_SEARCH_LIST", query.q);
        } else {
          redirect('/');
        }
      } catch {
         error({ message: 'Page not found' });
      }
    },

    mounted () {
      this.$store.commit('openSearch');
      this.$store.commit('setFromPage', fromPage);

      if (this.data.length == 0 || this.data === null) {
        this.$store.dispatch("GET_SEARCH_LIST", this.query);
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
          this.showSlideUpAnimation = true;
      }, 100);
    },

    beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
      fromPage = from.path;
      next();
    },

    beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
      next();
    },

    beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
      const search = document.getElementById('search');

      next();

      if (search && search.value.length) {
        this.$store.commit('closeSearch');
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

In my routes section it is defined as follows:

```
{
  name: 'search',
  path: '/search',
  component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/search/index').default
}
```

It is supposed to be a real-time search engine. I would appreciate your help in solving this problem...

Comment: I appreciate trying to help with the question, but when I saw that question, your answers didn't help me to solve mine. Its publication is from a search engine but not in real time.

Comment: How can this be avoided, friend?

Comment: if you `goToRoute()` run this then it will load data realtime ?

Comment: It is supposed to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NavigationDuplicated Navigating to current location ("/search") is not allowed \[vuejs\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57837758/navigationduplicated-navigating-to-current-location-search-is-not-allowed)

Comment: I am going to update the code by adding the other section of the search engine so that I can understand more.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [debounce](https://techformist.com/reusable-debounce-function-vue/). What it does is that it wait or delay till the user had finished typing before the model get updated or before you send it to the server.

An example of how it works is [here](https://vuejs-tips.github.io/v-debounce/)

Here is a package for it.
https://github.com/vuejs-tips/v-debounce