# Check Auth on routes not working in Vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I am adding auth on vue routes but it is not redirecting back to login page.

Giving this error

```
Error: Navigation cancelled from "/" to "/pages/login" with a new navigation.
```

Here is how I appliedt it on routes

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

  

    // If auth required, check login. If login fails redirect to login page

    if (!(auth.isAuthenticated())) {

        router.push({ path: '/pages/login', name: 'page-login', component: '@/views/pages/login/Login.vue' })
       

    }

    return next()
       

})
```

I think it is inside the loop and and redirecting too many times

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right. Your guard is pushing to the login route infinite times because `router.beforeEach` method is triggered in every route navigation including the login. To avoid this you should differ between the routes that require authentication and those that don't. You can do this by adding
`meta: {requiresAuth: true,},` on the routes you want to guard. This results in your route to look like:

```
{
  path: '/',
  component: Home,
  meta: {
    requiresAuth: true,
  },
}
```

You can then check if the route you're heading to requires authentication by adding: `if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth))` condition in your`beforeEach` method. This results in your guard looking like:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (!(auth.isAuthenticated())) {
      router.push({ path: '/pages/login', name: 'page-login', component: '@/views/pages/login/Login.vue' })
    }
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

This will let you check authentication on required routes only and you can break the infinite loop by adding

```
meta: {
  requiresAuth: false,
},
```

on your login route.

Comment: I need help on one new problem too

Comment: Now i am getting this error ```app.js:50316 Uncaught (in promise) NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/pages/login".```

Comment: Well, this is telling you that you are trying to navigate to the same route you're currently in. This may be occurring because the login route is still guarded. If that is not the reason you might want to check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58747480/10970649

Comment: I didn't understand can you please give example of my case?

Comment: In your guard, you are telling vue to push to `"/pages/login"` route if user is not authenticated. So if you set `requiresAuth` to true on the login route, it will try to push to the `pages/login` route again.

Comment: but on login route i have set ```requiresAuth``` false

Comment: Does it successfully route you to login when you're not authenticated?

Comment: It gives error only when i click on login button after that it works fine

Comment: authentication is working perfectly ,, after clicking on login it should move to dashboard but it consider that user is not authenticated and then again move to it

Comment: In that case, you should check if the auth property is being set before you push to dashboard, because before going to dashboard the `beforeEach` method gets triggered and if the auth property is not set yet it will reroute you to the login page.

Comment: how i can check current route?

Comment: try `console.log(auth.isAuthenticated())` in the if condition to check if the auth is set when going to the dashboard route.