# Vue router beforeEach: caught in loop and cannot load login template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a tricky issue using beforeEach in my Vue.router. I would like to check that a token is valid before going to the next page and redirect to the login page if it returns false. However, I also want to not load the login page if the validation is true if a user navigates to it from another URL.

The code I have at the moment seems to be causing an infinite loop and will not load the login page. This is the code I have so far.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => { 
    store.dispatch('validateTokenWithFM',{token: store.getFMToken})
      .then((r) => {
        console.log('TOKEN STILL VALID....', r)
        if(r){
          console.log('TOKEN OK', r)
          next() // REDIRECT TO PAGE
        } else {
          console.log('TOKEN EXPIRED')
          next('/login') // GO TO LOGIN
        }
      }).catch(err => { // If any other error returned go to login
        console.log(err)  
        next('/login')

      })
});
```

I seems that redirecting to the login is causing the token validation check to repeat on itself, creating the loop. But I am not sure how to circumvent that. I might be overlooking something simple. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: It's common to set some [route meta field data](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html) indicating which routes require authentication. You can then check that in your navigation guards to decide whether or not to validate tokens, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I originally posted a solution for vue-router v4.x here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68009594/1219079

I repeat it here again, maybe it will be useful.

It make use of vue-router V4.x and a global `beforeEach` guard.

Remember: vue-router 4.x discourages the use of `next()` (https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#optional-third-argument-next).

The use cases are:

1. user asks for `https://app.com/` without being already authorized;
2. user asks for `https://app.com/` being already authorized;
3. user asks for any available routing, which requires auth or not.

**Routes:**

```js
const routes = [
  /**
   * Routes not requiring auth
   */
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/NotAuthorizedLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        name: 'LOGIN',
        component: () => import('pages/Login.vue') 
      },
      {
        path: 'emailsignup',
        component: () => import('pages/EmailSignup.vue') 
      },
      {
        path: 'forgottenpassword',
        component: () => import('pages/ForgottenPassword.vue') 
      }
    ]
  },

  /**
   * Routes requiring auth
   */
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/AuthorizedLayout.vue'),
    meta: { requiresAuth: true },
    children: [
      { 
        path: 'authors',
        name: 'AUTHORS',
        component: () => import('pages/Authors.vue') 
      },
      { path: 'profile', component: () => import('pages/userProfile/index.vue') }
    ]
  }
];
```

**beforeEach global guard:**

```js
  const redirectToLogin = route => {
    const LOGIN = 'LOGIN';
    if (route.name != LOGIN) {
      return { name: LOGIN, replace: true, query: { redirectFrom: route.fullPath } };
    }
  };

  const redirectToHome = route => {
    const DEFAULT = 'AUTHORS';
    return { name: DEFAULT, replace: true };
  };

  Router.beforeEach((to, from) => {
    const userIsAuthenticated = store.getters['authentication/userIsAuthenticated'];
    const requiresAuth = to.matched.some((route) => route.meta && route.meta.requiresAuth);

    if (!userIsAuthenticated && to.fullPath === '/') {
      return redirectToLogin(to);
    }

    if (!userIsAuthenticated && requiresAuth) {
      return redirectToLogin(to);
    }

    if (to.fullPath === '/') {
      return redirectToHome(to);
    }

    return true;
  });
```