# Vue routing not working when using webpack. Main page works, but subpaths 404

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, vue-router

Prior to using webpack, my vue routing was working just fine. However, I started running into a bunch of loader issues so decided to use webpack. However, after getting my webpack running the main page loads fine, but all my routes now 404. Everything that has been commented out is something that I have already tried out, but didn't work. I believe there is something that is off with my webpack config file, but I can't figure it out. Any ideas or help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

## App.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="base-app">
    <div class="mapbox" id="mapbox">
      <router-view />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// import Login from './components/login.vue';
// import Tract from './components/tract.vue';

export default {
  name: "App",
  // components: {
  //   Login,
  //   Tract
  // }
};
</script>
```

## router.js

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";
import Index from "./components/index.vue";
import Login from "./components/login.vue";
import Tract from "./components/tract.vue";

const routes =  [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: Index
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: "/tract/:id",
    component: Tract
  }
];


const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

## main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
// import login from './components/login.vue';
// import tract from './components/tract.vue';
import router from './router.js';

import "./assets/styles/normalize.css";
import "./assets/styles/app.css"; 

const app = createApp(App);
// app.component('login', login);
// app.component('tract', tract);
app.use(router);
app.mount('#app');
```

## webpack.config.cjs

```
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: "./src/main.js",
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'main.bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: "vue-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              esModule: false,
            },
          },
          "css-loader",
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: () => [autoprefixer()],
              }
            },
          },
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].[contenthash:8].css",
      chunkFilename: "[name].[contenthash:8].css",
    }),
    new htmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
      favicon: "./public/favicon.ico",
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.vue' ],
    alias: {
        'vue': '@vue/runtime-dom'
    }
  },
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

## vue.config.cjs

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true,
    devMiddleware: {
      writeToDisk: false
    }
  }
}
```

## package.json

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "startdev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --config ./webpack.config.cjs",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./webpack.config.cjs"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/ui-vue": "^3.1.20",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.3.3",
    "axios": "^0.22.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.6.0",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.0",
    "core-js": "^3.34.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.6.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.3.3",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-chartjs": "^5.2.0",
    "vue-router": "4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.4",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.32",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "vue-loader": "^17.3.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.15",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  },
}
```

Comment: is the issue with development mode or production mode?

Comment: The issue is in development mode

Comment: yeah, I just noticed its vue 3 - I've never used vue 3 with `vue-cli` + `webpack` - so, good luck

Comment: Have a look at Vite, it makes this much easier. Webpack with Vue 3 is not something that is really supported as the officially supported build agent: https://kinsta.com/blog/vite-vs-webpack/

Comment: @recoilnetworks Vite ended being the solution. Thank you so much for your suggestion!

Answer (score -1):

You should remove the `webpack.config.js` and use only `vue.config.js`

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "marc-diff-checker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "coa": "2.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.2.16",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.13.14",
    "@mdi/font": "^7.0.96",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.6.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "postcss-url": "^7.3.2",
    "sass": "1.32.8",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "stylelint": "^13.9.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^20.0.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^3.18.0",
    "stylelint-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.3"
  }
}
```

## vue.config.js

```js
'use strict';
const path = require('path');
const pk = require('./package.json');

module.exports =
{
  devServer:
  {
    port: 8080,
    client:
    {
      //logging: 'info',
      overlay:
      {
        errors: true,
        warnings: true,
        runtimeErrors: false,
      },
    }
  },
  lintOnSave: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 'error' : false,
  css:
  {
    sourceMap: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
    /*
    loaderOptions:
    {
      postcss:
      {
        postcssOptions:
        {
          // without this Webpack complains that there is no PostCSS config inside the Vuetify/dist folder
          config: path.resolve(__dirname, '.postcssrc.js'),
        }
      },
    }
    */
  },
  productionSourceMap: true,
  configureWebpack: config =>
  {
    let parent;
    let dir = path.resolve(__dirname);
    const parsed = path.parse(dir);
    while (parsed.root !== dir)
    {
      dir = path.dirname(dir);
      parent = dir + (parsed.root !== dir ? path.sep : '') + 'node_modules';
      config.resolve.modules.push(parent);
      config.resolveLoader.modules.push(parent);
    }

    config.devtool = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'inline-source-map' : false; // other modes often break hot-reload and/or breakpoints
    if (!config.performance) config.performance = {};
    config.performance.hints = false;
  },
  chainWebpack: config =>
  {
    config.resolve.symlinks(false);
    config.resolve.alias.set('src', path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'));

    // !!!!!!! -- https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2978#issuecomment-441426094
    config.output.devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate(info =>
    {
      const resPath = path.normalize(info.resourcePath).split(path.sep).join('/');
      const isVue = resPath.match(/\.vue$/) && resPath.match(/^src/);
      //const isScript = info.query.match(/type=script/);
      //const hasModuleId = info.moduleId !== '';
      const isGenerated = info.allLoaders;

      const generated = `webpack-generated:///${resPath}?${info.hash}`;
      const vuesource = `vue-source:///${resPath}`;

      return isVue && !isGenerated ? vuesource : generated;
    });
    config.output.devtoolFallbackModuleFilenameTemplate('webpack:///[resource-path]?[hash]');

    // plugin options must be wrapped inside Array - otherwise error "non-callable @@iterator"
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
    {
      config.plugin('stylelintVue')
        .use(require('stylelint-webpack-plugin'),
          [
            {
              context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
              configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, 'stylelint.config.js'),
              files: '**/*.{vue,css,scss}',
              globbyOptions: { extension: false }, // otherwise "fastGlob" does not find anything if the folder contains brace(s)
              quiet: false,
              emitErrors: true
            }
          ]);
    }

    config.plugin('define')
      .tap(args =>
      {
        args[0]['process.env'].BUILD_TIME = JSON.stringify((new Date()).toISOString());
        args[0]['process.env'].VERSION = JSON.stringify(pk.version);
        return args;
      });
    return config;
  }
};
```

## src/main.js

```js
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router.js';

const myApp = createApp({
  name: 'RootApp',
  render()
  {
    return h(App);
  }
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
{
  myApp.config.errorHandler = (err, vm, info) =>
  {
    // err: error trace
    // vm: component in which error occurred
    // info: Vue specific error information such as lifecycle hooks, events etc.
    console.error(vm.$options._componentTag + ': ' + info, err);
    events.$emit(SNACKBAR_FAILURE, vm.$options._componentTag + '\n' + info + '\n' + err.message + '\n' + err.stack);
  };

  window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error)
  {
    alert('Error at ' + lineno + ':' + colno + ' in "' + source + '"\n' + message + '\n' + error);
  };
}

///myApp.config.globalProperties.$ajax = AJAX;
myApp.config.productionTip = false;
myApp.config.performance = false; // process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
myApp.config.devtools = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

myApp.use(router);
myApp.mount('#app');
```

## src/router.js

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';

import BadRoute from './views/BadRoute';
import Login from './views/auth/LoginPage';

const createHistory = createWebHistory;
const router = createRouter({
  scrollBehavior: () => ({
    left: 0,
    top: 0
  }),
  history: createHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Login,
      meta:
        {
          public: true
        }
    },
    // Always leave this as last one,
    // but you can also remove it
    {
      path: '/:catchAll(.*)*',
      component: BadRoute,
      meta:
        {
          title: 'NOT FOUND',
          public: true
        }
    }
  ],
});

router.afterEach((to, from) =>
{
  let title = to.meta.title;
  if (typeof title === 'function') title = title(to);
  if (title)
  {
    document.title = title;
  }
  else document.title = 'File History Diff';
});

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/63263736 - ignore NavigationDuplicated errors but keep other errors
const originalPush = router.push;
router.push = function push(location, onResolve, onReject)
{
  if (onResolve || onReject)
  {
    return originalPush.call(this, location, onResolve, onReject);
  }

  return originalPush.call(this, location).catch((err) =>
  {
    if (err && err.name === 'NavigationDuplicated')
    {
      return err;
    }

    return Promise.reject(err);
  });
};

export default router;
```

## src/App.vue

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <CustomHeader />
    <v-main>
      <router-view v-if="$route.meta.public || ($route.meta.admin ? $root.isAdmin : ($root.user || {}).uid)" :key="$root.refresh" v-slot="{Component}" class="pa-4">
        <transition name="fade" appear mode="out-in">
          <component :is="Component" />
        </transition>
      </router-view>
    </v-main>
    <CustomFooter />
    <v-overlay :value="$root.spin > 0" z-index="998">
      <v-progress-circular indeterminate size="64" />
    </v-overlay>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import CustomHeader from './views/layout/MainHeader.vue';
import CustomFooter from './views/layout/MainFooter.vue';
import events, { USER_CHANGED } from './events.js';

export default
{
  name: 'App',
  components:
    {
      CustomHeader,
      CustomFooter,
    },
  created()
  {
    events.$on(USER_CHANGED, this.reload);
  },
  beforeUnmount()
  {
    events.$off(USER_CHANGED, this.reload);
  },
  methods:
  {
    reload()
    {
      this.$root.refresh++;
    },
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  .fade-enter-active,
  .fade-leave-active
  {
    transition: all 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1);
  }

  .fade-enter,
  .fade-leave-active
  {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(-2em, 0);
  }

  .must_login
  {
    filter: blur(7px);
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Incorrect! The official build package for Vue 3 is Vite therefore, Webpack should be removed and Vite should be used instead.

Comment: @recoilnetworks The OP asked explicitly about Webpack - not about Vite. Read carefully the title of the question. I also use Webpack in my projects (soon to be replaced by RsPack) rather than Vite because Vite too often does not allow setting breakpoints in the original `.vue` file, only in the compilted `.js` files which is a significant inconvenience that is still not solved.

Comment: You are correct, my apologies. Based on what I know, Vue 3 does not officially support Webpack and instead recommends Vite which was the reason for my response.

Comment: Vite is okay in everything besides debugging - and that's the only reason I still have to use Webpack :(((

Comment: debugging what exactly? I have no issues using Vite in fact, I much prefer it over Webpack! I have written more than 4 applications using Vite + Vue 3 and have had no problems debugging, building or deploying.

Comment: @recoilnetworks My issue is that when I want to put a breakpoint in Chrome DevTools - I can put it only inside the JavaScript code that is produced by Vite but not inside the `<script>` section in my original `.vue` files. So I am left looking at the compiled code rather than the original code. Maybe your experience is different. Mine with Vite v4 was less than desirable regarding the debugging.

Comment: Ah, I do not use breakpoints, I just use simple console logs and what not to debug. Breakpoints do not really do not much for me. I do not necessarily care if the rest of the code runs or not after a certain point. If I do not want it to run, I just comment it out and move on. No big deal. I don't even use the Vue DevTools.

Comment: @recoilnetworks I use VueDevTools heavily and versions after 5.3 have glitches way too often - losing connection to the Vue app (e.g. after some hot-update it is no longer possible to change the value of component variables) or not loading all tabs (e.g. it often loads only Components and Timeline tabs but not Routes and Vuex/Pinia). I use breakpoints heavily since I need to inspect the behavior of the code - just logging is not enough, I need to see what causes some values to change. If Vite works for you - that's fine, but does not mean it's a panacea for everyone else.